# foobar2000 usage of id3 rating tags

Tags: mp3, foobar2000, id3

foobar2000 seems to be [mapping](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Foobar2000:ID3_Tag_Mapping) `%rating%` tags to the id3v2+ tag using [POPM](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#Popularimeter) with the value of `"POPM:Windows Media Player 9 Series"`, and remapping values (1,2,3,4,5) to (1, 64, 128, 196, 255). It does not set the play count portion of the `POPM` tag.

Is there any way to change the `"Windows Media Player 9 Series"` string to my own email address, as the POPM spec states? And, is there any way to set the play count attribute of this tag?

Does anyone actually use this POPM tag, or am I better off just enabling the old-style `TXXX:rating` tags?

Note: Yes, I have tried [foo_playcount](https://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_playcount) and I dislike it because it stores metadata in its own database and not in id3 tags, making my files not portable, and though it does include a "sync to tags" manual option, that option does not write ratings, only playcounts